# How can I run a command in mac terminal for multiple files in a folder in one go?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, terminal

How can I run the same command in mac terminal for multiple files in a folder? The files are named like `24538_7#1_paired1.fq`, `24538_7#1_paired2.fq`, `24538_7#2_paired1.fq`, `24538_7#2_paired2.fq`, `24538_7#3_paired1.fq`, `24538_7#3_paired2.fq`, and so on.

The command is:

```
STAR --runThreadN 12 --genomeDir indices/STAR --twopassMode Basic --readFilesIn data/24538_7#1_paired1.fq data/24538_7#1_paired2.fq --outFileNamePrefix results/STAR/
```

Since filename involves a counter, so, obviously the filenames need to be changed.

I was trying to write command, but it's giving segmentation fault. My effort for the command is below:

```
for file in 24538_7#*.fq; do STAR --runThreadN 12 --genomeDir indices/STAR --twopassMode Basic --readFilesIn data/"${file%.fq}_paired1.fq" data/"${file%.fq}_paired2.fq" --outFileNamePrefix results/STAR/ ; done
```

(PS- I use MacOS)

Comment: Put some debugging `echo` into the loop to see which execution of `STAR` gives you the segfault

Comment: can you please elaborate @nohillside

Comment: Well, I assume that one of your calls to `STAR` crashes so you need to look at its input.

Comment: Will each set of files only have 2 members in the pair?  Both 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes @Jesse_b, every file is paired. Please see question above for the type of file names.

Comment: Ah, one additional question: How many files will match ` 24538_7#*.fq`?

Comment: There are 384 cells, so 768 files in total (384 with paired1 and 384 with paired2 at the end. ) @nohillside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over all the `paired1.fq` files and for each such file, use the name to compute the name of the corresponding `paired2.fq` file. Then call your program with these:

```bash
for paired1 in data/*paired1.fq; do
    paired2="${paired1%1.fq}2.fq"  # remove 1.fq from end of name and replace with 2.fq

    if [ ! -f "$paired2" ]; then
        printf 'Missing file:\t%s\n' "$paired2" >&2
        continue
    fi

    prefix="${paired1%_*}" # remove last underscore and everything after
    prefix="${prefix##*/}" # remove directory name from prefix

    # If $paired1 is the string "data/24538_7#1_paired1.fq", then
    # $prefix should now be "24538_7#1"

    mkdir -p "results/STAR/$prefix"

    STAR --runThreadN 12 --genomeDir indices/STAR --twopassMode Basic \
         --readFilesIn "$paired1" "$paired2" \
         --outFileNamePrefix "results/STAR/$prefix/"
done
```

Comment: this is working now but I got only 1 output file. For that I think we may have to include a counter with command(--outFileNamePrefix) also. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @AkhilVerma I don't know what you mean by "counter". How does the `--outFileNamePrefix` option work? Note that I don't know what `STAR` is.

Comment: by counter I mean `*` and I tried adding it after `results/STAR*` but it still gave only 1 output file. `STAR` is an alignment tool for `RNA seq analysis`.

Regarding the `--outFileNamePrefix`:

   --outFileNamePrefix
    default: ./
    string: output files name prefix (including full or relative path). Can only be
    defined on the command line.

Link to STAR Manual :(https://github.com/alexdobin/STAR/blob/master/doc/STARmanual.pdf)

Comment: @AkhilVerma See updated answer.

Comment: I ran it but still no luck with it. It's still giving only 1 output file. It's basically rewriting for each file. Can you please look into STAR manual and help me with it. (github.com/alexdobin/STAR/blob/master/doc/STARmanual.pdf)

Comment: @AkhilVerma I did. What is the one output file called? Does the option's argument need to be an existing directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78794/discussion-between-akhil-verma-and-kusalananda).

Comment: @AkhilVerma Now updated with output directory creation and corrected spelling of `paired` when creating the `prefix` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter expansion isn't trimming enough.

You are setting `file` to:

```
file=24538_7#1_paired1.fq
```

Then trimming `.fq`:

```
$ echo ${file%.fq}
24538_7#1_paired1
```

Then adding `_paired1.fq`:

```
$ echo "${file%.fq}_paired1.fq"
24538_7#1_paired1_paired1.fq
```

---

Try like this:

```
for file in 24538_7#*.fq; do 
    STAR --runThreadN 12 --genomeDir indices/STAR --twopassMode Basic --readFilesIn data/"${file%_paired?.fq}_paired1.fq" data/"${file%_paired?.fq}_paired2.fq" --outFileNamePrefix results/STAR/
done
```

This is going to run twice per pair though since each pair has two files.  I think that may not be what you need.

---

To run once per pair you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=( 24538_7#*.fq )
files=( printf '%s\n' "${files[@]#24538_7#}" | sort -n | awk -F_ '{print $1}' | uniq )

for n in "${files[@]}"; do
    STAR --runThreadN 12 --genomeDir indices/STAR --twopassMode Basic --readFilesIn data/"24538_7#${n}_paired1.fq" data/"24538_7#${n}_paired2.fq" --outFileNamePrefix results/STAR/ 
done
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm getting error for each file like this:  

    EXITING because of fatal input ERROR: could not open readFilesIn=/Volumes/Pegasus/Users/Akhil/SangerSeqData_Torp_Dec2017/Run24538_7_Plate3145_TorpWt/FastQ/testSTAR/24538_7#24538_7#1_paired1.fq_paired1.fq
        
    Jun 12 15:34:01 ...... FATAL ERROR, exiting  
@Jesse_b

Comment: @AkhilVerma:  Which one are you using?

Comment: The below one @Jesse_b

Comment: Are you running it exactly as I have posted? Can you remove the loop and just do: `echo "${files[@]}"` after the two variable assignments? It should just be a list of numbers

Comment: After running 
`files=( sort -n < <(printf '%s\n' "${files[@]#24538_7#}") | awk -F_ '{print $1}' | uniq )
`
I'm getting an error:
`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'`
Because of which `for n in "${files[@]}"; do
    STAR --runThreadN 12 --genomeDir indices/STAR --twopassMode Basic --readFilesIn data/"24538_7#${n}_paired1.fq" data/"24538_7#${n}_paired2.fq" --outFileNamePrefix results/STAR/ 
done` is generating the other errors: `EXITING because of fatal input ERROR: could not open readFilesIn=/Volumes/Pegasus/Users/Akhil/SangerSeqData_Torp_Dec2017/Run24538_7_Pl`....(see above)

Comment: @AkhilVerma:  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78797/discussion-between-akhil-verma-and-jesse-b).